# Indicatif de lisibilité d'un texte en français ?

Tags: ressources, linguistique

Il existe en anglais (et en ligne) de nombreux [analyseurs de textes](http://textalyser.net/?lang=fr) qui permettent de juger de la lisibilité d'un texte (analyse de la longueur moyenne des mots, de la quantité de vocabulaire différent, des répétitions...)

Cependant en m'y penchant de plus près j'ai vite réalisé que les « analyseurs » français utilisent les même algorithmes qu'en anglais, et ce n'est pas forcément adapté. Ils permettent de repérer les répétitions, de lister le vocabulaire utilisé, mais pour la lisibilité ils comparent les moyennes de longueur des mots utilisés avec les valeurs de référence de la langue anglaise. En rentrant un texte en français dans ces analyseurs on tombe presque toujours sur des valeurs qui annoncent que le texte est « difficile à comprendre », ou « dense ».

**Existe-t-il des indices particuliers pour la langue française ?**

**Existe-t-il des analyseurs de texte fiables pour la langue française ?**
(Bonus : gratuits et en ligne ?)

Comment: Une question intéressante, mon intuition serait qu'il n'existe rien de fiable ni pour le français ni pour l'anglais. La lisibilité est un concept difficile à définir...

Comment: Je sais qu'ils sont basés sur la diversité de vocabulaire (peu = facile à lire), sur la longueur des mots et des phrases. Donc c'est surtout indicatif (pour des textes commerciaux ou pour les webmasters) mais s'il y a des plages d'indices de "très lisible" à "texte littéraire" en anglais, je n'ai pas trouvé en français.

Comment: Sorry, I’m no help, but this is slightly similar to the reaction that my wife gets from her US middle-school French students when she tells them that the grades she made on her 1976 French Bac (ranging from 12.5/20 to 15/20) were well above average (all that her students stubbornly see is a range of 62.5% to 75%, which for them is failing to D-). Until you find (or better yet, CREATE) exactly what you’re looking for, maybe the best you can do is what my wife does, take the irrelevant results/reactions with a big grain of salt and, if possible, perhaps try to create your own conversion table.

Comment: Je suggère l'expérimentation ; avec [Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html) par exemple. Même quand on n'y connaît absolument rien (comme moi,  non développeur), on peut s'[amuser](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145462) à penser qu'on est capable de construire un _stemmer_ avec _sed_! On apprend beaucoup sur la langue à essayer de systématiser. Merci.

Comment: Quels autres outils as-tu déjà éssayés ? Qu'en est-il de http://labs.translated.net/lisibilite-texte/ et http://www.scolarius.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas [encore] d'analyseur de texte fiable pour des textes qui ne sont pas pré-formatés ou convenus.

Les texte de Loi ont tous le même niveau de complexité : langage juridique, expressions/tournures/formulations encadrées par un jargon ancestral, malgré les efforts fait récemment pour que tout texte réglementaire soit intelligible par tous.

Une analyse de texte ne se fait pas avec des statistiques de taille, de fréquence, de positionnement et des métrages divers, mais sur le sens des mots qui ont souvent deux ou trois définitions possibles et autant ou sinon plus de nuances selon le mot accolé, la place dans la phrase ou son contexte.

De plus les sous-entendus peuvent être nombreux, les exceptions variées et pas toujours très compréhensibles...

Chacun a sa vision selon son niveau d'apprentissage, son goût ou non pour la littérature, l'expression artistique, l'expression médiatique...

Le plus simple est de prendre les livres pour enfants, de la maternelle au collège, et de voir les mots employés, l'évolution des phrases, des définitions, *et d'en parler* avec quelqu'un qui enseigne la langue, qui vous dira sur quels problèmes buttent les élèves.

Industrialiser ou automatiser le processus vous fera perdre l'expérience des lecteurs qui d'un regard sur deux ou trois pages d'un livre peuvent vous donner des indices et les adapter à ceux que vous avez en tête.

D'autant plus que les langues latines et anglo-saxonnes n'ont pas les mêmes affects, la lecture est un problème humain, donc à la fois universel et unique : aucun texte n'est compris exactement de la même manière par deux personnes différentes.

Comment: Merci. Je suis d'accord et je pense qu'il n'existera jamais un outil automatique qui jugera qu'un texte est "bon" ou "mauvais". Mais ces indices et analyseurs existent en anglais et donnent une vague idée du type de texte (de la même façon que les statistiques donnent une idée des tendances mondiales sans être parfaites), d'où ma question.

Comment: @Tyrabel Score pour *http://www.scolarius.com/* avec choix du type *articles/nouvelle* dont la moyenne est *133 collégiale* ==>  §3 ci-dessus: 303 initié, le §4: 115  secondaire ; apparemment 100 points par ligne :), mais pas d'une difficulté trois fois supérieure ! Ce n'est pas la grammaire qui est la source du français, (elle coordonne une compréhension mutuelle, le Libre offre de bons correcteurs automatiques) mais tout ce qui peut être suggéré de l'indicible, tout ce qui échappe à une normalisation, à une subordination ou à une infantilisation de la pensée... ce qui est une autre histoire.